# Pico not finding python module

Tags: javascript, python, module

I'm trying to use Pico to call python modules through javascript, but I keep getting this error. Can anyone provide some insight?

> "GET
>   /pico/call/?_module=pico.server&_function=load&module_name=%22example%22&_callback=jsonp14922499508
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 426"

Some pico documentation: https://github.com/fergalwalsh/pico/wiki

Comment: Look in your error log.  That's just a line from your access log.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try this:

Copy the `.py` and `index.html` files to the pico root directory `/`

Try running the app from the root?

```
http://localhost:8800/
```

Comment: I'm also having the problem, and you suggestion did not make a difference.  Do you have any other thoughts?